# Where is it shown that homotopy sheaves form a higher stack?

Tags: reference-request, higher-category-theory

Many references on infinity categories etc. advertise that one application is that it's an appropriate setting to glue (the appropriate replacement for) derived categories of sheaves.

What's the canonical reference giving a precise formulation of this statement, and its proof?

Comment: It's not exactly what you're asking about, but maybe this old answer of mine can be useful: https://mathoverflow.net/a/236600